# Jenkins Docker image has no make or sudo

Tags: sudo, make, docker, jenkins

I'm trying to set up CI on AWS using the Jenkins image from the Docker hub. I've gotten a few hours into the process (configuring for a Node project), and I've now realized that a few of my npm dependencies require `make` in order to build. The Docker image doesn't have `make`, nor does it have `sudo`, so it looks like I'm unable to `apt-get install make`. Is there another way to get `make` without having to recreate the image with a Dockerfile that grants root access?

Comment: Do you know the root password?

Comment: @Paul I do not. The image was generated with this Dockerfile, however, if that gives any clues: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/8f909abee98247ad482efb6d21833e2054e3e9de/Dockerfile

Comment: I think you have to modify the Dockerfile. However, you can try to report your case as an enhancement -- don't specify `USER` in Dockerfile, but in the startup script.

Comment: @xuhdev Good advice. I've submitted an issue to the Jenkins Docker repo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image is a base official image, it has the minimal tools required for Jenkins to work, by design. There are people that want make, some want multiple versions of ruby, java, etc, some don't want anything in there because they use [agents](https://github.com/carlossg/jenkins-slave-docker) .

It also doesn't run as root for security reasons following the Docker official images guidelines

Check this to [extend the image and install more tools](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker#installing-more-tools)

Answer (score 3):

you can run this command, get bash in your container and then install whatever you want:
docker exec -it -u root jenkins bash
otherwise you can configure it into your [dockerfile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker#installing-more-tools)